# Integer solutions of $x+y+z=axyz$

Tags: diophantine-equations

let $x,y,z$ be 3 co-prime integers and $a$ a positive even integer. Find all the integer solutions of $$x+y+z=axyz$$ Any hints?
What I have done: Suppose there exist $rst\neq 0$ where $$y+z=rx$$ $$z+x=sy$$ $$x+y=tz$$ and 
$$1+r=ayz$$
$$1+s=azx$$
$$1+t=axy$$
and solve the system below by assuming $\triangle=0$
$$-rx+y+z=0  $$
$$x-sy+z=0   $$
$$x+y-tz=0  $$
$\triangle= r+s+t+2-rst=0    $
Hence,
$$a(xy+yz+zx)=1+rst=0$$
I feel like I am going on a circle...

Comment: How do you define coprime if $x, y, z=0?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to deal with the case where $xyz=0$.

If $xyz\not=0$, we have
$$a=\left|\frac{x+y+z}{xyz}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx}+\frac{1}{xy}\right|\le\frac{1}{|yz|}+\frac{1}{|zx|}+\frac{1}{|xy|}\le 3$$
from which we have to have
$$a=2$$
So, 
$$2\le \frac{1}{|yz|}+\frac{1}{|zx|}+\frac{1}{|xy|}\le 3\tag1$$

Supposing here that
$$|yz|\ge 2\quad\text{and}\quad |zx|\ge 2\quad\text{and}\quad |xy|\ge 2$$
gives
$$\frac{1}{|yz|}+\frac{1}{|zx|}+\frac{1}{|xy|}\le\frac 32$$
which contradicts $(1)$.

Therefore, we have
$$|yz|\lt 2\quad\text{or}\quad |zx|\lt 2\quad\text{or}\quad |xy|\lt 2,$$
i.e.
$$|yz|=1\quad\text{or}\quad |zx|=1\quad\text{or}\quad |xy|=1$$
I think that you can continue from here.

Comment: Is there a similar approach to deal with $x^n+y^n+z^n=axyz$ where $n$ is odd prime?